# How to create a hierarchical table of content like index with pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, grouping

Suppose I have a `DataFrame` of the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    { 
        'Heading 1': ['Cat 1'] * 5 + ['Cat 2'] * 5 + ['Cat 3'] * 5, 
        'Heading 2': ['Group 1'] * 2 + ['Group 2'] * 2 + [''] + ['Group 1'] * 2 + [''] * 2 + ['Group 2'] + [''] + ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3', 'Group 3'],
        'Heading 3': [f'Case {i}' for i in range(1, 6)] * 3
    }
)
```

Which looks like this (The actual data do not contain any digits at the end, this is just for illustration purposes):

```
# Source Data 

   Heading 1 Heading 2 Heading 3
0      Cat 1   Group 1    Case 1
1      Cat 1   Group 1    Case 2
2      Cat 1   Group 2    Case 3
3      Cat 1   Group 2    Case 4
4      Cat 1              Case 5
5      Cat 2   Group 1    Case 1
6      Cat 2   Group 1    Case 2
7      Cat 2              Case 3
8      Cat 2              Case 4
9      Cat 2   Group 2    Case 5
10     Cat 3              Case 1
11     Cat 3   Group 1    Case 2
12     Cat 3   Group 2    Case 3
13     Cat 3   Group 3    Case 4
14     Cat 3   Group 3    Case 5
```

I want to make a new column that is representative of the hierarchy of these columns so it looks like this:

```
# Desired Data

   Heading 1 Heading 2 Heading 3 Indexed
0      Cat 1   Group 1    Case 1   1.1.1    
1      Cat 1   Group 1    Case 2   1.1.2
2      Cat 1   Group 2    Case 3   1.2.1
3      Cat 1   Group 2    Case 4   1.2.2
4      Cat 1              Case 5     1.3
5      Cat 2   Group 1    Case 1   2.1.1
6      Cat 2   Group 1    Case 2   2.1.2
7      Cat 2              Case 3     2.2
8      Cat 2              Case 4     2.3
9      Cat 2   Group 2    Case 5   2.4.1
10     Cat 3              Case 1     3.1
11     Cat 3   Group 1    Case 2   3.2.1
12     Cat 3   Group 2    Case 3   3.3.1
13     Cat 3   Group 3    Case 4   3.4.1
14     Cat 3   Group 3    Case 5   3.4.2
```

How could one achieve this? I can get it indexed by the Heading 1 and 2, tried `df.set_index(list(df.columns)[:-1]).groupby(level=1).cumcount()` based on my understanding of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53164816/pandas-change-repeated-index-to-hierarchical-index), the structure looks like something I can use to build the "indexed" column but I'm struggling to get the correct numbers:

```
# Some sort of in between state...

Heading 1  Heading 2
Cat 1      Group 1      0
           Group 1      1
           Group 2      0
           Group 2      1
                        0
Cat 2      Group 1      2
           Group 1      3
                        1
                        2
           Group 2      2
Cat 3                   3
           Group 1      4
           Group 2      3
           Group 3      0
           Group 3      1
```

I know I can do a `apply` with a custom function to get this done, but is there a built-in `pandas` method that I'm missing here?

Edit: For clarity, my actual data do not contain digits and look more like this:

```
# Closer to actual data

             Main  Group    Case
0      Some Topic  Dummy  Case A
1      Some Topic  Dummy  Case B
2      Some Topic   Test  Case C
3      Some Topic   Test  Case D
4      Some Topic         Case E
5      Diff Topic    Foo  Case A
6      Diff Topic    Foo  Case B
7      Diff Topic         Case C
8      Diff Topic         Case D
9      Diff Topic    Bar  Case E
10  Another Topic         Case A
11  Another Topic    Baz  Case B
12  Another Topic    Uno  Case C
13  Another Topic    Dos  Case D
14  Another Topic   Tres  Case E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `shift` create the sub group then we just need to combine them

```
s1=df.mask(df=='').groupby(['Heading 1'])['Heading 2'].apply(lambda x : (x!=x.shift()).cumsum()).astype(str)
s2=df.groupby(['Heading 1','Heading 2']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
s=df['Heading 1'].str.split(' ').str[1]+'.'+s1+'.'+s2.mask(df['Heading 2']=='','')
s=s.str.strip('.')
s
Out[256]: 
0     1.1.1
1     1.1.2
2     1.2.1
3     1.2.2
4       1.3
5     2.1.1
6     2.1.2
7       2.2
8       2.3
9     2.4.1
10      3.1
11    3.2.1
12    3.3.1
13    3.4.1
14    3.4.2
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Still trying to understand the magic in the first two line... but question, if my actual data's "Heading 1" doesn't end with digits, is there an innate method to convert the heading count to `1, 2, 3...` or would I need an intermediate cum count column to achieve this?

Comment: @Krrr you need a cumcount for this

Comment: Always count on @WeNYoBen! I had to clean the data a little bit (some `NaN` were messing with the middle column) and used `s=(df['Heading 1'] != df['Heading 1'].shift()).astype(int).cumsum().astype(str)+'.'+s1+'.'+s2.mask(df['Heading 1']=='','')` instead.  But otherwise everything worked great! Thanks for the tips on `cumcount`!