# Pandas: Indexes with several related lines

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the `market_ticker` dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['EWZ US 05/29/20 P27', 'HSI US 12/30/20 C24800', 'TLT US 06/19/20 C225', 'EWZ US 05/29/20 P27'],
                   'Market': ['US NYSE', 'US NYSE', 'HK HKSE', 'US NYSE']})

df['Reduced_Ticker'] = df['Ticker'].apply(lambda a :" ".join(a.split(" ", 2)[:2]))

market_ticker = df[['Market','Reduced_Ticker']].groupby(['Market']).agg(list)
market_ticker['Reduced_Ticker'] = market_ticker['Reduced_Ticker'].apply(lambda x: pd.unique(x))
market_ticker
```

How can I transform each item in the list of indexes into a line related to the index itself? Output expected:

```
Market  |  Reduced_Ticker

HK SE   |     TLT US
_________________________       
              
US NYSE |  EWZ US
        |  HSI US
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explode:

```
market_ticker.explode('Reduce_Ticker')

    Reduced_Ticker
Market  
HK HKSE TLT US
US NYSE EWZ US
US NYSE HSI US
```

Comment: Was there any way of not repeating the indices? would it be like joining the two lines and placing a single US NYSE in the center?

Comment: It might be that you want to change your approah to multi indexing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53164816/pandas-change-repeated-index-to-hierarchical-index seems like it's on the right path

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

Actually you just need 1 more step on your original solution : explode on column `Reduced_Ticker`:

```
market_ticker = market_ticker.explode('Reduced_Ticker')
```

If you like, you can still refer to my solution below:

First, you create a new column called `Reduced_Ticker` by slicing the string from column `Ticker`. Then select only the columns you want (`Reduced_Ticker and Market`), followed by dropping duplicates.

```
df_out = (
    df
    .assign(Reduced_Ticker = df.Ticker.str[:6])
    [['Market','Reduced_Ticker']]
    .drop_duplicates()
)
```

This is the output `df_out`:

```
Market  Reduced_Ticker
US NYSE EWZ US
US NYSE HSI US
HK HKSE TLT US
```